# Tooltip for deleted post contains a snippet of a post

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, tooltips, flag-history

Flag summary page contains a list of flaged posts. Some of them are already deleted. I don't have enough rep to view [deleted post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3591/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-addthis) yet, but in this case I can see a some text from the post in the tooltip:

> [image: deleted post]

Is it security/priviledge overlook or by design?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Still need to fix text on the `That solved my problem!` button!

Comment: Hmm? Fix what text? Also, I wasn't pinged since only the last close voter can be pinged, saw this now by chance.